# Can't launch Node.js on OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, launch

I can't launch node. I have the message (on the screenshot).

I tried to delete, and install again, it didn't help.
Mac Os El Capitan.

Error: Could not open history file. REPL session history will not be persisted.

[image]

Comment: Explaining how you installed node might help you get answers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be a permissions issue with the user account you are launching node as.

By default node tries to store a .node_repl_history file in your home directory.

For example, running `ls -lah` in the directory this file is stored in will reveal the permissions and ownership set on the file.

Changing the permissions to give the account node is being executed as access to this file may fix this problem.

Also, you can change the location of this file by setting the NODE_REPL_HISTORY_FILE environment variable.

https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_environment_variable_options

Comment: NODE_REPL_HISTORY_FILE  deprecated in 20v use NODE_REPL_HISTORY

Answer (score 1):

Its a known bug which was fixed.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3610
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3630

Try to upgrade to a newer version.

P.S
what is your node version?

`node --version`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Tyler, it is indeed permission issue. Changing permission should solve the issue.

```
sudo chown <user> .node*
```